# Django Doesn't serve CSS code From Static Folder

Tags: html, css, django

Need some help with django. Seems that somehow i can't change the css of my home page.

These are my static settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

In my index_home.html page i want to put a background image e.g. marea.jpg which is in static/img/marea.jpg.

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
{% load static %}
<title>Romanii din Italia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="static/css/custom.css" />
<link href="{% static 'css/custom.css'   %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/static/css/custom.css" />
</head>

<body> 
<div class='container'> 
    <ol class='breadcrumb'>

        <li><a href='{% url "posts:home" %}'>Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href='{% url "posts:list" %}'>Stiri</a></li>



        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "register" %}'>Register</a></li>
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "login" %}'>Login</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "logout" %}'>Logout</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ol>
</div>


<div class="container" >
    <h2>Bine ati venit pe site-ul romanilor din Italia!</h2>
        <div class="row" id="primapoza" style="background-image: url('/static/img/roma.jpg');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;height: calc(100vh - 71px);">
        <div class="col-xs-12 offset-xs-0 col-sm-4 offset-sm-4 section-title" >
            <br><br>
        <p id="banner-text"> Romani in Italia! </p>
  <!--    <p id="banner-text" style="text-align: center;font-size:40px;!important;font-color:white;!important;margin-left: 100px;"> Romani in Italia! </p> -->

    </div>
</div>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

And this is my custom.css which doesn't change my css code. Can someone pls advise? Thank you in advance!

```
h1 {
    color: #777777;
}

.wmd-panel{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.comment-reply{
    display:none;
}

#banner-text{
    font-color:white;!important;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

I can customize the CSS only with inline code e.g `<p id="banner-text" style="margin-left: 400;font-color: black;font-size:30">Romani in Italia!</p`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% load static %}`  and `{% load staticfiles  %}`   under head tag in html

Answer (score -2):

Based on my understand of how `{% load static %}` is used and what the [Django documentation is saying](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/), I don't think you're using `{% load static %}` correctly.  I've always used it right above whatever my static link were to be.

For example, in your html doc head, it should be

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'>
```

Otherwise, I don't think your stylesheet is linked to your html doc.  Try that and also correct that mistake anywhere else you may have it, and it should be working.

You can't have `{% load static %}` at the top of your file and expect it to apply for the whole page.  It needs to be right above whatever your static file is, as many times as you use it.

Comment: This is a strange mix of correct and totally wrong. It's correct that load static shouldn't be in the CSS file itself, but wrong to say that it doesn't apply to a whole file: on the contrary, that if exactly how loading template tags works.

Comment: Turns out I've been using the tag redundantly in my code, I guess.  So you *can* paste {% load static %} once atop your file and it'll apply for the whole file?  I think I had unrelated problems with this and wrongly associated these two since.

Comment: it didnt work with static files tag in the html head.